# How to change unity greeter logo position?

Tags: unity, unity-greeter

I have changed **unity-greeter** logo successfully by replacing desired logo to `/usr/share/unity-greeter/logo.png` Now I want to change the position of the logo. Is it possible? I use 14.04 64-bit os

Answer (score 0):

it's not clear really on where you want it. from playing with changing my logo on the login screen, it seems that if you go higher than about 90 pixels for height then it will drop it below the screen..this may vary based on resolution and then to make it move side to side you would need to change your canvas size to something wider and move the image to the appropriate location on the canvas. If you're trying to place it in some completely other location, that's beyond me. *some other location like the top*